# How to reuse the terminal after I ran a Bokeh app in the server

Tags: python, pandas, terminal, bokeh

I am working currently with Bokeh and Python. However, every time I ran my script into the server and I close the page where the server deploys my script, I cannot use again the terminal while is blocked with the message.

```
WebSocket connection closed: code=1001, reason=None
```

Does anyone know how to reuse the terminal?

Thank you in advance!

WebSocket connection closed: code=1001, reason=None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Ctrl + C to send a terminating signal, this will close the Bokeh server so you can reuse the terminal. (This isn't just for Bokeh, it also works for other applications!)

Comment: Thank you, my problem was I was closing the app window before ctrl + C, for instance the console was not responding somehow. Anyway it was solved and thanks a lot !